# HTML5 video can not paly and media request abored

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm working in MEAN STACK application. I'm facing one problem in video loading.
My local server does the video play, but in my live server following issue comes up.

```
 In Firebug

           Url                     status       

GET home_video.mp4                 206 Partial Content
GET home_video.mp4                 Aborted
```

One thing: Sometimes the video plays very well right after some page refreshes.

> dependencies

```
html5 video tag  
nodejs server  
angularjs
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to send the full video to the client at once.

You need to implement `Accept Ranges` header and send video in part.

You can read more about it [here](http://blog.dojchinovski.mk/?p=41)